# Can I set labels for subplots simultaneously?

Tags: matplotlib

I have several axis in a subplot which require some of the same labels.  I was hoping I could simply map the feature to the axes by

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots(ncols= 10, nrows = 10, figsize = (20,10))
    *Plotting Commands*
map(lambda x: x.set_ylabel('Value'), ax)
```

This doesn't seem to work, but there are no errors raised.  Any way I could apply a label to several axes at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the code the raise an error. `ax` is in this case a 2D numpy array. If you iterate over it, you iterate over its rows, which are numpy arrays as well. Hence something like

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel'
```

should be raised.

However, you may flatten the `ax` array before mapping.

```
map(lambda x: x.set_ylabel('Value'), ax.flatten())
```

This would result in the desired plot

[image]

Comment: Oh, flattening it was the key.  OK, that's awesome, thanks.